# How to fix a while syntax error in python?

Tags: python

I'm getting a syntax error on my 2nd while loop. Can't figure out why, any help appreciated :)

```
#intro
print("Welcome to my prime number detector.")
print("Provide an integer and I will determine if it is prime.")

#again loop
again = "Y"
while again == "Y":
    num = (int(input("Enter an integer"))

    #check for valid input
    while num < 1:
        num = (int(input("Enter an integer"))

    #test for prime 
    for d in range(2,num):
        if (num % d) == 0:
            print(num,"is not prime.")
        else:
            print(num,"is prime.")

    #ask again
    again = intput("Do you want to play again? (Y/N)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` in the two of your following lines. The correct line of code is

```
num = (int(input("Enter an integer")))
```

Also, as sheepez mentioned below, your outer brackets are redundant. You can simply use

```
num = int(input("Enter an integer"))
```

Comment: The outermost brackets are also redundant, and were they not there the error probably would have been more obvious.

Comment: @sheepez: I agree but I wanted mainly to point out the error in the spirit of OP's question. But let me acknowledge you in my edit

Comment: Why would someone downvote such an answer?